Esp Now not sending or not receiving
I'm a beginner trying esp now for the first time. I have two Adafruit QT Py ESP32-C3 boards and I'm trying to make one board send a message, and the second board print on serial that it received the message.
Even though all my configuration seems to go through successfully (I never get any ESP error codes), all I get from my debug messages is that everytime the send callback runs, it gets called with a "failure" as a result.
Also, my receiver is never executing its receive callback, so its serial log is just constantly quiet.
So far I've tried setting the wifi channel of the peer in the sender, to make sure it matches the receiver, interchanging which board is sender and which one is receiver, changing from platformIO to arduino IDE, disabling my LED indicators and only keeping my serial port messages active.
I've also tried the code straight out of some tutorials I've seen on the topic and all messages still fail to send.
Tutorials I've used:
dronebotworkshop
randomnerd
volosproject
Any ideas on why all my send messages are failing / nothing is being received? Thanks!!
This is what the serial port looks like on the sender (COM4):
34:85:18:17:DC:2C
ESP-NOW init OK
send callback registered OK
Peer added
Wifi channel:
1
Attempting to send 0
esp_now_send sent complete
Failed to send
Attempting to send 1
Callback invoked with status: 1
esp_now_send sent complete
Failed to send


and here is the serial port on the receiver (COM3):
34:85:18:17:EA:28
ESP-NOW init OK
receive calback registered OK
Wifi channel:
1

SENDER CODE:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
// #include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include "controllerGlobals.h"

// Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(NUM_PIXELS, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800); // create led strip

// Helper function to set color
// void setLEDColor(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue) {
//     strip.setPixelColor(0, strip.Color(red, green, blue)); // Set color for first pixel
//     strip.show();
// }

esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;
uint8_t data = 0;
uint8_t sentFailed= 1; // 0 = success, 1 = failed


void sendDataCb(const uint8_t* macAddress, esp_now_send_status_t sentStatus) {
  Serial.printf("Callback invoked with status: %d\n", sentStatus);
  if(sentStatus == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS)
  {
    sentFailed = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    //ERROR: FAILED TO SEND
    sentFailed = 1;
  }
}

void blinkSendResult()
{
  if(sentFailed)
  {
    //ERROR: FAILED TO SEND
    Serial.println("Failed to send");
    // for(short i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    // {
    //   setLEDColor(LED_RED);
    //   usleep(250*1000); //sleep 250ms
    //   setLEDColor(LED_OFF);
    //   usleep(250*1000); //sleep 250ms
    // }
  }
  else
  {
    // successful send!
    Serial.println("Successful send!");
    // for(short i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    // {
    //   setLEDColor(LED_GREEN);
    //   usleep(500*1000); //sleep 250ms
    //   setLEDColor(LED_OFF);
    //   usleep(500*1000); //sleep 250ms
    // }
    sentFailed = 1; //reset sentfailed flag for next loop
  }
}

void setup() {
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_OTHER_VAL); //115200

  //INITIALIZE LED
  // strip.begin();       // Initialize the Neopixel library
  // strip.setBrightness(10); // Set brightness (0 to 255; 50 is about 20% brightness)
  // strip.show();        // Turn off all LEDs initially

  // initialize wifi module in station mode
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  // WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.channel(1);

  // print mac address to serial port
  // sleep(5);
  delay(5000);
  // Serial.printf("%s\n", String(WiFi.macAddress()).c_str());
  Serial.println(String(WiFi.macAddress()));

  // initialize esp-now protocol
  if(esp_now_init() == ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("ESP-NOW init OK");
  }
  if (esp_now_register_send_cb(sendDataCb) == ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("send callback registered OK");
  }
  
  //register esp-now peer 
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, receiverAddr, 6);
  peerInfo.channel = 1;  
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;
  // Add peer        
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Peer added");
  }
  Serial.println("Wifi channel:");
  Serial.println(WiFi.channel());

}

void loop() {

  Serial.printf("Attempting to send %d\n", data);
  // sleep(3);
  // delay(500);
  // setLEDColor(LED_YELLOW);
  // sleep(3);
  // delay(1000);
  // setLEDColor(LED_OFF);
  // sleep(3);
  delay(1000);
  if(esp_now_send(peerInfo.peer_addr, (uint8_t*)&data, sizeof(data)) != ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("esp_now_send failed");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("esp_now_send sent complete");
  }
  blinkSendResult();
  data = (data) ? 0 : 1;
}

RECEIVER CODE:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include "controllerGlobals.h"

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(NUM_PIXELS, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800); // create led strip

// Helper function to set color
void setLEDColor(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue) {
    strip.setPixelColor(0, strip.Color(red, green, blue)); // Set color for first pixel
    strip.show();
}

uint8_t data = 2;

void recvDataCb(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  Serial.println("Callback invoked");
  memcpy(&data, incomingData, sizeof(data));
  if(data == 0)
  {
    // reset data value
    data = 2;
    setLEDColor(LED_GREEN);
    sleep(1);
  }
  else if(data == 1)
  {
    // reset data value
    data = 2;
    setLEDColor(LED_BLUE);
    sleep(1);
  }
  else
  {
    // reset data value
    data = 2;
    setLEDColor(LED_RED);
    sleep(1);
  }
}


void setup() {
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_OTHER_VAL); //115200

  //INITIALIZE LED
  strip.begin();       // Initialize the Neopixel library
  strip.setBrightness(10); // Set brightness (0 to 255; 50 is about 20% brightness)
  strip.show();        // Turn off all LEDs initially

  // initialize wifi module in station mode
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  // WiFi.disconnect();

  // print mac address to serial port
  sleep(5);
  Serial.println(String(WiFi.macAddress()));

  // initialize esp-now protocol
  if(esp_now_init() == ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("ESP-NOW init OK");
  }
  // esp_err_t cbregistration = esp_now_register_recv_cb(recvDataCb);
  if(esp_now_register_recv_cb(recvDataCb) == ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("receive calback registered OK");
  }
  Serial.println("Wifi channel:");
  Serial.println(WiFi.channel());
}

void loop() {
  // Serial.println("Waiting LED ON");
  // setLEDColor(LED_YELLOW);
  // usleep(250*1000); //sleep 250ms
  // Serial.println("Waiting LED OFF");
  // setLEDColor(LED_OFF);
  // delay(1000);

}


controllerGlobals.h
#include <Arduino.h>

#define LED_PIN 2       // Neopixel data pin (GPIO 2 for QT Py ESP32-C3)
#define NUM_PIXELS 1    // Number of LEDs (typically 1 for the built-in Neopixel)
// color definitions for LED
#define LED_RED 255,0,0
#define LED_GREEN 0,255,0
#define LED_BLUE 0,0,255
#define LED_YELLOW 255,255,0
#define LED_OFF 0,0,0

const uint8_t receiverAddr[] = {0x34, 0x85, 0x18, 0x17, 0xEA, 0x28}; //receiver -- com3
// const uint8_t receiverAddr[] = {0x34, 0x85, 0x18, 0x17, 0xDC, 0x2C}; //sender -- com4



OK, so both of these devices are connecting to your wifi access point, and i assume they are being assigned an IP address.  At that point, they are just internet endpoints, exactly as if they had an internet cable.  You will use normal TCP/IP socket APIs to set up a server on the first system, and connect to that server on the second system.  I don't see you doing any of that.

Hi Tim. I'm not attempting to connect either of these to my wifi network.  To my understanding, ESP-NOW is a protocol that is supposed to work independently of a wifi access point, so they won't need an IP address and to my understanding I'm nos supposed to use any TCP/IP API.

@TimRoberts, ESP-NOW is a peer-to-peer communication protocol. Both tx and rx are in STA_MODE, but It does not establish a tcp/ip connection. See documentation.

@WKGuy, your code is based on some quite old tutorial and old ESP-IDF api. Not sure what is your IDE installation and version, have you take a look at the latest ESP-NOW examples, all the APIs have changed significantly.

@hcheung thank you for the extra info about the API. I didn't know my examples were so outdated. I loaded the minimal example scripts from what you sent and the behavior is still the same though. The master keepss ending stuff and the salve never seems to get anything. It just sits at Setup complete. Waiting for a master to broadcast a message... Any extra clues? From what I'm gathering on these examples, it is not necessary to tell the master the mac address of the slaves anymore and viceversa, correct?

Man, computers have Extra Sensory Perception? Am I the only person here that thinks this is WAY cooler than AI?

I think problem is both send and receive are station mode. WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); .
In station mode, ESP will act just like your smartphone or laptop. It will connect to an existing WiFi channel. AP mode WiFi hotspot with a custom SSID and Password and other smart devices will be able to connect. Source
